# Expanding ggmap output and getting rid of grey

Tags: r, ggmap

Can anyone assist with expanding my ggmap output?

I used [this site](https://blog.dominodatalab.com/geographic-visualization-with-rs-ggmaps/) as a model from which to make my own map

dummy data:

```
df <- data.frame(Current_zip_code=c(27103, 27540, 32669, 32765, 39180, 39553, 47403, 70118, 70119, 70364, 74114, 74133, 83703, 90045, 90263, 90278, 96706, 96707, 99506), total=c(1, 5, 7, 12, 15, 6, 17, 31, 12, 13, 6, 4, 4, 25, 41, 65, 33, 25, 22), latitude=c(36.066545, 35.643545, 29.640613, 28.656375, 32.292761, 30.400599, 39.121719, 29.952305, 29.974504, 29.626988, 36.126894, 36.04309, 43.668396, 33.960041, 34.035087, 33.871214, 21.338055, 21.345535, 61.224384), longitude=c(-80.30733, -78.83486, -82.59446, -81.21026, -90.87184, -88.65092, -86.57409, -90.12347, -90.08747, -90.72076, -95.94657, -95.88417, -116.25707, -118.3949, -118.70752, -118.37177, -158.02499, -158.08587, -149.77461))

library(fiftystater)
data("usa")
usa_center = as.numeric(geocode("United States"))
USAMap = ggmap(get_googlemap(center=usa_center, scale=2, zoom=4), extent="normal")

map_ex <- USAMap +
   geom_point(aes(x=longitude, y=latitude), data=df, col="orange", alpha=0.4, size=df$total*.2) + 
   scale_size_continuous(range=range(df$total))
```

[image]

the output map was off center. is there any way to expand it to include our friends in Alaska and Hawaii? I don't like the grey background and axis titles. any way to expand and get rid of the grey and axis?

I tried adding this

```
scale_x_continuous( limits = c( -95.5 , -95.3 ) , expand = c( 0 , 0 ) )
```

but i received an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points in `df` are outside the `USAMap` area.
It is possibile to drop the gray area in `map_ex` setting the range of its x and y axes to the same values of the `USAMap` axes range.

```
df <- data.frame(Current_zip_code=c(27103, 27540, 32669, 32765, 39180, 39553, 
47403, 70118, 70119, 70364, 74114, 74133, 83703, 90045, 90263, 90278, 96706, 
96707, 99506), total=c(1, 5, 7, 12, 15, 6, 17, 31, 12, 13, 6, 4, 4, 25, 41, 
65, 33, 25, 22), latitude=c(36.066545, 35.643545, 29.640613, 28.656375, 32.292761, 
30.400599, 39.121719, 29.952305, 29.974504, 29.626988, 36.126894, 36.04309, 
43.668396, 33.960041, 34.035087, 33.871214, 21.338055, 21.345535, 61.224384), 
longitude=c(-80.30733, -78.83486, -82.59446, -81.21026, -90.87184, -88.65092, 
-86.57409, -90.12347, -90.08747, -90.72076, -95.94657, -95.88417, -116.25707, 
-118.3949, -118.70752, -118.37177, -158.02499, -158.08587, -149.77461))

library(ggmap)   
usa_center <- as.numeric(geocode("United States"))
usa_center_map <- get_googlemap(center=usa_center, scale=2, zoom=4)
USAMap <- ggmap(usa_center_map, extent="normal")

# Get axes range of USAMap
axis_range <- attr(usa_center_map, "bb")

# Set axes range using the "limits" option of 
# scale_x_continuous and scale_y_continuous
map_ex <- USAMap +
   geom_point(aes(x=longitude, y=latitude), data=df, 
                  col="orange", alpha=0.4, size=df$total*.2) + 
   scale_size_continuous(range=range(df$total)) +
   scale_x_continuous(limits=c(axis_range$ll.lon,axis_range$ur.lon)) +
   scale_y_continuous(limits=c(axis_range$ll.lat,axis_range$ur.lat))
map_ex
```

[image]

Otherwise, you can download a larger map that includes all the points in `df`.

```
us_map <- get_googlemap(center=c(-110,45), scale=2, zoom=3, size = c(640, 500))
map_ex <- ggmap(us_map) +
   geom_point(aes(x=longitude, y=latitude), data=df, 
                  col="orange", alpha=0.4, size=df$total*.2) + 
   scale_size_continuous(range=range(df$total)) 
map_ex
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for this code! But I can't seem to see the plots in Alaska or Hawaii. the last three data records have plots in those states. How can I edit that to include them?